# Re-enable mirroring with git-svn

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

For some time now I've been mirroring a Subversion repository to a Git repository. Which has always worked fine. However, due to a crash of a virtual server and not having a backup I've got to setup the mirror again. The repository I need to track is almost 1200 commits big and contains a lot of files (which is the main reason for the Git mirror, as it's so much faster to checkout a copy of the repo).

What I need to do now is make my freshly cloned Git mirror make track the Subversion repository again. I've got no problems adding the new remote ref but can't seem to figure out how to be able to pull svn commits into the Git branch again.

One error I seem to receive is `Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history`.

How can I re-enable mirroring a Subversion repository on a existing Git branch that's only behind a couple commits from the Subversion repository?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no simple way to do that. (And if there is a complicated way, I don't know about it.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to get it to work again is to copy over the `.git/svn` directory from the original, as this is where extra svn metadata are tracked (assuming the git-svn config is the same).

However, since you don't have it try this:

1. `git svn init http://hostname/svn/repository` with any other parameters you used before (maybe `-s`?)
2. `git checkout` the latest commit from svn.
3. Recreate the `git-svn` ref: `git update-ref refs/remotes/git-svn HEAD` (or if you used `-s`, this should be `refs/remotes/trunk` instead)
4. Fetch the latest from svn since the current commit: `git svn fetch --parent`. This should rebuild git-svn metadata for your entire history.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick! I can't award the bounty yet (will have to wait for 9 hours it seems)

Comment: I don't quite understand the `git checkout` passage. What should I checkout?

Comment: A likely candidate is `master`, unless you've been committing on `master` since you got latest from git-svn. Basically you want to `checkout` the last commit you see in `git log` that has SVN information in the commit message, so that git-svn can pick up where it left off.

Comment: `git svn fetch --parent` returns "Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history" for me, and `git svn fetch` throws messages like "Rebuilding .git/svn/refs/remotes/git-svn/.rev_map.<GUID>" many times. If try to run `git svn fetch` again, when it does output the same result. I think .git internals is broken somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I found another method at http://trac.parrot.org/parrot/wiki/git-svn-tutorial:

> Adding git-svn metadata to the github clone
>
> If you want to re-populate the SVN metadata that can quickly be done
>   by taking your up-to-date clone of leto's repo off of gihub and adding
>   this to your .git/config
>
> ```
> [svn-remote "svn"]
>         url = https://svn.parrot.org/parrot
>         fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
> ```
>
> Then run this command to find the "top commit"
>
> ```
>  git show origin/upstream | head -n 1
> ```
>
> and put that commit hash into a file .git/refs/remotes/trunk
>   (obviously replace the has with the one from the above command)
>
> ```
>  echo c85aaa38b99cedb087e5f6fb69ce6d4a6ac57a0b > .git/refs/remotes/trunk
> ```
>
> and finally
>
> ```
>  git svn fetch
> ```